# session variable- data table null value- asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-variables

i cant seem to determine why my session variable returns null in the print item click event. The data table is present prior to the session variable.

Any advise is appreciated.

```
    protected void btnGetOrderData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Class1 x = new Class1(); // create a new instance of class1

        x.sopnumbe = txtOrder.Text; // pass the class string the value of text box order 

        DataSet ds = x.GetOrderData(); // call get order from class1 "x" instance 

        DataTable orderDataTable = ds.Tables[0]; // dataset to datatable (first)

        Session["sess_dt"] = orderDataTable; // create a session var to store dataset and use elsewhere


        //  GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        //  GridView1.DataBind();

    }

    protected void btnPrintItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["sess_dt"];
```

Answer (score 0):

To store:

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 Session["sess_dt"] = orderDataTable;
```

To retrieve:

```
 DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["sess_dt"];
```

Check your `orderDataTable` if has a value.

Comment: Yes. It has a value at that point. It's is null after retrieving on the final line. I'm hoping someone knows why.

Comment: If it were `null` the cast would fail.

Comment: maybe you have a problem on converting the session to DataTable?

Try to use this: 
DataTable dt = Session["sess_dt"] as DataTable